# Text Alignment in Pango Markup Language

Tags: html, alignment, gstreamer, pango

Written a markup like this

`<span font-desc="Bold 40" foreground="blue" size="x-large">P <b>S</b> </span>`

with the help of the following [link](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Markup.html)
The above markup can be fed to the textoverlay element as a [text property](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/pango/textoverlay.html?gi-language=c) of Gstreamer.
I am not getting the way to align the text. Example if i want to add the text in center or left or right. How can i do that.

Comment: Thanks for your question. You can improve it by showing us also how did you tried.
I sugest you to read this Stack Overflow guide "How do I ask a good question?": https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't think you have a real canvas in this element for that kind of positioning. It allows text formatting - basic positioning is done via the element properties.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch Thanks for the reply, actually i want to display text using pango at the top and end of an image simultaneously. Any clue on that

Comment: I think you need two `textoverlay` overlays then. Put them in a row..

Comment: @FlorianZwoch ya thats one solution, but was thinking if it can be possible via pango .